# What does f '(z) means?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

[image]
.

I see the derivative of **'w' with respect to 'z'** all the time, what does it mean though? Derivative of **'w' with respect to 'theta'** makes sense which is a vector on the argand graph.

Comment: Here $w$ is a function $z$. In general if $z$ is the complex variable and $w$ is real-differentiable, then $w$ has two partial derivatives (with respect to $Re(z)$ and $Im(z)$) but it is no obvious what $w'(z)$ is, **except when $w(z)$ is analytic** (which is the case here with $w(z) = z^2$), therefore it has a well-defined complex derivative. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_function and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations

Answer (score 1):

Differentiable complex functions are locally just like rotation and rescaling. Rotation by arg $f'(z)$ and rescaling by $|f(z)|$.
 I will give you some intuition about why that is the case, but before that, a definition.

A function $f$ is *holomorphic* at $z$ if the limit
$$ f'(z)= \lim_{h\rightarrow0} \frac{f(z-h)}{h}$$ exists and is finite.
A function $f$ is *holomorphic* on a subset of the complex plane if for all $z$ in that subset $f'(z)$ is a well defined continuous function.

Now you know from high-school that if $f$ is a real, differentiable function at $x_0$ you can write a *linear approximation* of $f$ around $x_0$. That is, for $x-x_0$ small enough
$$f(x) \sim f(x_0) + f'(x_0) (x-x_0) $$

Now, for pretty much the same reasons, if $f$ is a complex function,  *holomorphic* at $z_0$, then for |z-z_0| small enough 
$$f(z) \sim f(z_0) + f'(z_0) (z-z_0) $$

Hopefully, now you can see that, while the derivative of a real function can be thought of as the slope of the graph, one can think of the derivative of a complex function as the rotation and stretching of the complex plane by the function. Can you see why?

There is one caveat: if $f'(z)=0$, then this stretching and rotating picture breaks down. This points are called critical points. Your function has one at 0.

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to the image, $w$ is $f(z)$. Its derivative with respect to $z$ is...

Generally, $w$ is used to represent 'another' complex plane. The complex $z$-plane is generally the domain or original complex plane, and the complex $w$-plane is generally the codomain or transformed complex plane. There isn't really much to it, it's just a 'convention' letter like $y=f(x)$ for real functions.